# Excel VBA: Error 1004 application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: excel, range, vba

I am having trouble debugging a code I wrote. It runns fine until a certain point and then stops and shows: **runtime error 1004 application-defined or object-defined error**.

I have not written VBA in a very long time so my code might be a mess =).

The problem seems to be with: see comment 'Generate UID for the Current Imp

```
'Sheet Definitions
strSourceSheet = "MasterReport"
strComponentSheet = "UniqueIdComponents"

'defines row where data starts
intEntryCount = 2
intImpCount = 0

'determine maximum number of rows for both sheets
lngMaxRowSS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSourceSheet).UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
lngMaxRowCS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strComponentSheet).UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

'Run until there are no more entries
For intEntryCount = 2 To lngMaxRowSS

   'Prevents to overwrite existing UIDs
   If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSourceSheet).Range("BP" & intEntryCount) = "" Then

    'Recieve next imperative on the Source List to find according UID Components
    strSourceImperative = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSourceSheet).Range("A" & intEntryCount)

        'Run until no new Imp UID is defind
        For intImpCount = 11 To lngMaxRowCS

            'Location of Imps on Component Sheet
            strComponentImperative = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strComponentSheet).Range("C" & intImpCount)

            ' If the Source Imp = Component Imp then we create a UID for that Source IP
            If strSourceImperative = strComponentImperative Then

                'Assign Column to UID component in order to find the Column in the MasterReport
                strUIDComponent1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strComponentSheet).Range("D" & intImpCount)
                strUIDComponent2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strComponentSheet).Range("E" & intImpCount)
                strUIDComponent3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strComponentSheet).Range("F" & intImpCount)
                strUIDComponent4 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strComponentSheet).Range("G" & intImpCount)
                strUIDComponent5 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strComponentSheet).Range("H" & intImpCount)
                strUIDComponent6 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strComponentSheet).Range("I" & intImpCount)
                strUIDComponent7 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strComponentSheet).Range("J" & intImpCount)

                'Generate UID for the Current Imp
                strUID = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSourceSheet).Range(strUIDComponent1 & intEntryCount) _
                        & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSourceSheet).Range(strUIDComponent2 & intEntryCount) _
                        & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSourceSheet).Range(strUIDComponent3 & intEntryCount) _
                        & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSourceSheet).Range(strUIDComponent4 & intEntryCount) _
                        & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSourceSheet).Range(strUIDComponent5 & intEntryCount) _
                        & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSourceSheet).Range(strUIDComponent6 & intEntryCount) _
                        & ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSourceSheet).Range(strUIDComponent7 & intEntryCount)

                'Writes UID into MasterReport
                'ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSourceSheet).Range("BP" & intEntryCount) = strUID

                'Test Writes
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Test").Range("A" & intEntryCount) = strUID

            'If the Source Imp = Component Imp then we created a UID for that Source IP
            End If

        'If the two Source Imp <> Component Imp, go to next row on Component sheet and compare again
        Next intImpCount

   'Prevented to overwrite existing UIDs
   End If

Next intEntryCount
```

In the case where i get the error the components are A,M,N,O,BK,"","" and the Entry count is 5718. It wrote 5718 entries just fine and then shows the Error.

Any Ideas?

Thanks in advance for your help!!

Comment: The code you have posted does not make any sense at all. Perhaps you should post more of your code and describe what you are trying to achieve with it.

Comment: Here is what it does:

strUID is a Unique ID that is composed of a number of Cell Values. These values can be different depending on how many and which components (columns) a user chooses.

since the values of the components are stored in cells, I use the strUIDComponent(s) to tell me which column and intEntryCount which row.

I create the strUID by adding multiple cells together (see code) and then print it in a different sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking `ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSourceSheet)` out to a `With` statement and substituting values, you appear to be saying this statement is equivalent to:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(strSourceSheet)

  strUID = .Range("A" & 5718) & _
           .Range("M" & 5718) _
           .Range("N" & 5718) _
           .Range("O" & 5718) _
           .Range("BK" & 5718) _
           .Range("" & 5718) _
           .Range("" & 5718)

End With
```

The last two entries are not valid ranges.

I cannot test this code but something like this might meet your requirements:

```
  Dim WkShtComp As Worksheet
  Dim WkShtSrc As Worksheet
  Dim ColMast As String

  With ThisWorkbook
    Set WkShtComp = .Sheets(strComponentSheet)
    Set WkShtSrc = .Sheets(strSourceSheet)
  End With

  strUID = ""
  For Each ColMast in Array("D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J")
     strUIDComponent = WKShtComp.Range(ColMast & intImpCount).Value
     If strUIDComponent <> "" Then
       strUID = strUID & WkShtSrc.Range(strUIDComponent & intEntryCount).Value
     Endif
  Next
```

Comment: Your code is what it would look like, yes. I also thought that the "" might be a problem, but until 5718 it worked and I had many such UID's missing the last 2 components (that would have been ""). and it wrote them just fine.

But since it is not proper code, i would rather fix it. Any ideas how i could exclude the ""'s without having to write 7 seperate IF statements? 

I am not really good with VBA so that is about as creative as i can get haha

Comment: It is difficult to make suggestions without a better understanding of what you are doing.  I would consider making `strUIDComponent` an array or going make a step and making `strUID` in a loop directly without use the `strUIDComponent`s as intermediaries.